# Paging splitting? I forget the term >_<

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a mySQL query (select * from obs.Queries) to pages, I totally forget the term... I found a few "paging" scripts, but they all look really awful with deprecated mysql_* instead of PDO or whatever

Does anyone know what I should be searching for/are there any good examples?

I don't need actual pages split, just `$_GET['offset']` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination; http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html

The link is an ok walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT is what you're looking for.

`SELECT * FROM OBS.QUERIES LIMIT 10, 20`

Starting at row **10**, return **20** rows.  Typically you would put the page number the user is currently on in the URL and use $_GET['offset'] as you mentioned.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM obs.Queries LIMIT' . $_GET['offset'] * 5 . ',5';
```

That will give you 5 entries per page.

But remember to sanitize your input before sending it off. Like checking that $_GET['offset'] is numeric (is_numeric()) and extracting the integer value (intval()). Also $_GET['offset'] must in this case always be set so you are probably better off storing the page in a variable you assign based on whether or not offset is supplied or not.